# How can I fix the 'sh' term not recognized error when installing flyctl on PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, fly

I have been trying to install flyctl on my Windows 10 system with the command mentioned on the website:

`curl -L https://fly.io/install.sh | sh`

when I run the above command, I get the following error message:

```
sh : The term 'sh' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:37
+ curl -L https://fly.io/install.sh | sh
+                                     ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (sh:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I was trying to Install flyctl From fly.io Website

Comment: sh is the Bourne shell on Unix so obviously it won't be available on Windows unless you're using some POSIX environment on Windows like wsl, wsl2, cygwin or msys and even if you have, the above install.sh script is tailored for Linux and might not work at all on Windows. Did you even read the [installation documentation on fly.io](https://fly.io/docs/hands-on/install-flyctl/)?

Answer (score 2):

As @phuclv mentioned in the comment, you need to run the task specified for your OS (operating system).

For Windows, the installation process is:

```
pwsh -Command "iwr https://fly.io/install.ps1 -useb | iex"
```

The link to the docs: https://fly.io/docs/hands-on/install-flyctl/#windows

Comment: I didn't recognize `iex`; it's an alias for [`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-7.3).

Comment: Exactly! It's an alias. You can check running: Get-Alias -Name iex

Comment: Minor point but production PowerShell code should not use aliases - see [Don't use aliases in scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/shell/using-aliases?view=powershell-7.3#dont-use-aliases-in-scripts). The fly install script should not use `iex`.